# Dynamic row numbering in html table

Tags: html, dynamic, html-table

I am building an html table dynamically, meaning that sometimes there will be different rows displayed or not displayed depending on certain other conditions.  Sometimes only these rows are visible:

```
1
3
4
7
9
```

and other times it might be these rows which are visible:

```
2
3
5
8
```

Basically what I am trying to say is that there could be any combination of rows.  What I want to be able to do is to display the row number (or letter) for each row, consecutively.  In my first example, the five rows would be numbered consecutively from 1 to 5, and in the second example the 4 rows would be numbered consecutively from 1 to 4.

What would be an efficient way to accomplish this, dynamic row numbering?

Comment: How are you creating this table?

Comment: There are about 30 possible rows which are already written.  I need to be able to display and not display rows, depending on the value of of other variables, but at the end of the day I want to maintain my consecutive row numbering regardless of whichever rows happen to be displayed or not.

Comment: are you able to use a scripting language?  Or is it strictly HTML?  If it's just HTML then using javascript is really your only way.

Comment: @Robert scripting language = haven't learned that.  javascript, how?  can you point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference on creating HTML tables using javascript: 
http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/htmljs.html

If you need to use variables to display / not display rows then this should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read some about jQuery or other javascript libraries.

I suggest you provide a better, more detailed explanation and perhaps some code - if you have any - to give us a better understanding of your problem.